# JSView - Set trigger, when loses focus, on custom tag

Tags: jquery, jsviews, lost-focus, custom-tag

I'm trying to define a custom tag for input-elements, which only trigger, when the input-element lost focus. 
When it triggers, it should modify the data-linked item.
The data-manipulation is working onAfterChange.

```
//jsview html tag
<script id="input_text_layout" type="text/x-jsrender">
      <input type="text" data-link="{:value:} {testvalidation value}">
    </script>

//jQuery Part
$.views.tags({
  testvalidation: {
    baseTag: "radiogroup",
    linkedElement: "select,textarea,input",
    init: function(tagCtx, linkCtx, ctx) {
      var tag = this;
    },
    onAfterChange : function(ev, eventArgs) {
      $.observable(this.linkCtx.view.data).setProperty("info_text", "Testinformation");
    }
}
});

})(this.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `trigger=false` if you want updates to be triggered on the blur event, rather than on keydown/input. The setting can be global, on the individual tag, or in the tag definition.

See

- http://www.jsviews.com/#link2way@trigger
- http://www.jsviews.com/#jsvsettings/trigger

Setting `trigger=false` on the tag definition for a custom tag looks like this (your tag):

```
testvalidation: {
  linkedElement: "input",
  trigger: false,
  onAfterChange : function(ev, eventArgs) {
    $.observable(this.linkCtx.view.data).setProperty("info_text", "Testinformation");
  }
}
```

or this one from *http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/tag-controls/simple-textbox*:

```
textbox: {
  linkedElement: "input",
  template: "<input/>",
  onUpdate: false,
  trigger: false,
  dataBoundOnly: true
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works without dedicated data-link.
Before: 
<input type="text" data-link="{:value:} {testvalidation value}">
New:
<input type="text" data-link="{testvalidation value}">